# If $A_1$ and $A_2$ are unitary matrices ,and if $CA_1C^{-1}=A_2$,then is $C$ is also unitary?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, unitary-matrices

$A_1$ and $A_2$ are matrix of the same unitary transformation, w.r.t different orthonormal basis. And $C$ is the transition matrix(hence, $CA_1C^{-1}=A_2$).
To show if $A_1$ and $A_2$ are unitary matrices then $C$ is also unitary.
where unitary means $AA^*=A^*A=I$, $A^*$ is the adjoint of $A$.

I have been trying this , but could not come with proof.

Comment: You'll need further constraints. See what happens if e.g. you double $C$.

Comment: @J.G. i didn't get what you mean by double $C$. sorry, I have edited my question, is this okay now?

Comment: What I mean is replacing $C$ with $2C$ doesn't change whether $CA_1C^{-1}=A_2$, but may change whether $C$ is unitary (if it was before, then it won't be afterwards). Maybe the equation should be $CA_1C^\dagger=A_2$.

Comment: @J.G. i see now. But i suppose assuming $C$ the transition matrix will avoid this problem.

Comment: If you mean you want to add the assumption $C$ is a transition matrix, plus edit that into the question. Then we can start tidying up these comments.

Comment: @J.G. i have edited the question

Comment: @Rkb Doubling $C$ does not affect whether or not it works as a transition matrix

Comment: The answer to your question is definitely negative. Consider $A_1=A_2=I$ for instance.

Answer (score 2):

The edits really improved the question. Now the answer is pretty much already in the way you state it.

EDIT: the last comment by user1551 made me realize that the matter is not quite as simple as I thought. Something in below answer is wrong but I am not quite sure what or where. PROCEED WITH CAUTION! (End of edit)

In the new version $A_1$ describes linear transformation $A$ w.r.t. orthonormal basis $B_1$ and $A_2$ describes the same transformation $A$ w.r.t. basis $B_2$. This means that we know what $C$ does: it maps basis $B_1$ to basis $B_2$!

Now unitary means 'preserves the inner product' which in human language means 'preserves angles and distances'. It is pretty obvious that $C$ does indeed do this for the elements of $B_1$: they all have length 1 and their images are elements of $B_2$ so these images *also* have length one. Similar the angle between two elements of $B_1$ equals the angle between their images under $C$, namely 90 degrees (or $\pi/2$ radians).

The question then remains: 'okay, $C$ preserves angles and distances (or more general: the inner product) when applied to the finitely many elements of the basis $B_1$ but does that imply that it does the same when applied to general vectors?'

And the answer is 'well yeah, that is (more or less) what $B_1$ being a basis *means*'.

(This way of formulating things may feel a bit too informal for your taste, but it can easily be formalized when we accept the definition of unitary as 'preserving the inner product'. The link with the definition $A^*A = I$ is then that the inner product of $u$ and $v$ in this language is $u^*v$ so that the inner product of $Au$ and $Av$ becomes $(Au)*(Av) = (u^*A^*)(Av) = u^*(A^*A)v^*$, which equals $uv$ *for all $u$ and $v$* if and only if $A^*A = I$.)